# Python Dash dropdown opens after returning None value to it, how can I close it?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Here is my code, after clicking the closing button on the modal, the dropdown opens with the options and it is really annoying. My goal is to somehow close the dropdown or not re open it, after I click the close button, but I need to use it after closing, so a permanent `disabled=True` is not a solution.

```py
    def dropdownMaker(self):
        dropdown=dcc.Dropdown(id='inspection_dropdown', placeholder='examine',
                                        options=[{'label': 'BTC', 'value': 'BTC'},
                                                {'label': 'S&P500', 'value': 'S&P500'}],
                                                style={"margin-top":"25px"}
                            )
        return dropdown

    def updateModalCallback(self,app):
        app.callback(
            Output("modal", "is_open"),
            [Input("inspection_dropdown", "value"),Input("close", "n_clicks")],
            State("modal", "is_open")
            )(self.updateModal)

    def updateModal(self,value,n_clicks,is_open):
        print("updateModal fut")
        if (value!=None or n_clicks):
            return not is_open
        return is_open
    
    def clearDropdownCallback(self,app):
        app.callback(
            Output("inspection_dropdown", "value"),
            Input("close", "n_clicks"),
            )(self.clearDropdown)



    def clearDropdown(self,n):
        return None
```

Here you can see the program when I click on the dropdown options and after closing the modal. How can I close this "temporarily"?
[image: Here you can see the program when I click on the dropdown options]

[image: after closing the modal]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the focus after the closing of the modal, somehow the focus is going to this input, change it to another element

document.getElementById("YOUR-ELEMENT-ID").focus();